# Current through a loop symmetric about a current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

For part (b) where the current i is increasing, the answer is apparently that loops 1 and 3 have zero current induced. This doesn't make sense to me. The magnetic flux is changing through the area of the loop, so an emf must be induced in the loop, giving rise to a current, which produces a magnetic field that acts to reduce the change in flux.

Can anyone please explain why I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, I realised my mistake.

Look at loop 1 for example. The current through the wire is producing a magnetic flux coming **out of the page** through the top half of the loop, but going **into the page** through the bottom half of the loop, so the net change in flux is 0.